# How to check message errors with the new Twilio API?

Tags: c#, twilio

I'm upgrading some code that was using the old Twilio C# API to the new API, and I can't figure out how you're meant to check for errors after sending the message now.  All the examples I can see do no error checking.  So the old code is this:

```
var attemptWithAlphanumericId = client.SendMessage(fromName, to, message);

if (attemptWithAlphanumericId.RestException == null)
{
    return !string.Equals(attemptWithAlphanumericId.Status, "failed", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}

if (attemptWithAlphanumericId.RestException.Status == "400"
    && attemptWithAlphanumericId.RestException.Code == "21212")
{
    var attemptWithFallbackNumber = client.SendMessage(fallbackNumber, to, message);

    if (attemptWithFallbackNumber.RestException == null)
    {
        return !string.Equals(attemptWithFallbackNumber.Status, "failed", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    throw new InvalidOperationException(attemptWithFallbackNumber.RestException.Message);
}

throw new InvalidOperationException(attemptWithAlphanumericId.RestException.Message);
```

But with the new API style which I've started to use:

```
var twilioResponseMessage = MessageResource.Create(
    to: new PhoneNumber(to),
    from: new PhoneNumber(_from),
    body: message
);
```

... there's no `RestException` property on the response message object.  How am I meant to check `RestException`'s status and code?

Comment: The new library will raise a TwilioException which you can catch in a try/catch block.

Comment: Got a link to the docs on that?

Comment: I do now :)  We just added these today.  Sorry it wasn't there before, that's definitely an oversight on our part. https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/csharp#handle-errors
and https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/csharp/migrating-your-csharp-dot-net-application-twilio-sdk-4x-5x#handling-errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

We don't have specific docs on catching errors when sending SMS messages I'm afraid. I can try to give an example though (I'm not really a C# developer, but if I'm wrong I bet Devin can correct me ). It should look a little like this:

```
try {
    var twilioResponseMessage = MessageResource.Create(
        to: new PhoneNumber(to),
        from: new PhoneNumber(_from),
        body: message
    );
catch (TwilioException e) {
    Response.Write(string.Format($"Error: {e.Message}"));
}
```

There is an example of making API calls and catching errors in [the quickstart guide to making phone calls with C#](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/csharp/rest/call-request).

Let me know if that helps at all.

**edit**

After reading your comment, I realise there is more to this!

Your original code is trying to send a message using an alphanumeric ID and if that fails, fallback to a regular number. There is actually a better way to achieve this using [Messaging Services](https://www.twilio.com/console/sms/services) within Twilio.

Messaging Services wrap up a bunch of features around number pooling for sending SMS messages. In your case, a messaging service can be set up with an alpha sender ID and a fallback number. Then, when you [use the service to send an SMS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/messaging/send-messages-copilot) it will try the alpha sender ID first and fallback to your number, just like your code currently does. This can eliminate one level of catching errors in your application and leave that logic to the messaging service. Your code only needs to deal with errors in contacting the API then.

Here's how you'd do that.

Create a messaging service in your Twilio console. Add your fallback number to the number pool. [Add an alphanumeric sender ID to the copilot features](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133867-Using-Alphanumeric-Sender-ID-with-Messaging-Services). Take the messaging service sid and use it in the following code:

```
try {
    var message = MessageResource.Create(
        to: new PhoneNumber(to),
        messagingServiceSid: "YOUR_MESSAGING_SERVICE_SID",
        body: message
    );
    return !string.Equals(message.Status, "failed", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
catch (TwilioException e) {
    throw new InvalidOperationException(e.Message);
}
```

I believe that using the messaging service like this, and handling the exception in this way will replicate the behaviour you already had, leave the alpha sender/fallback number logic to Twilio and let you update your library.

Comment: What I'm trying to figure out is the new equivalent of what was being done before.  Before, it was apparently checking for an HTTP 400 and then checking `RestException.Code` before checking whether `Status` was "failed".  I'm not really sure what that would look like with the new API.

Comment: You were checking for a 400 error because you were trying to see if you needed to retry without using an alphanumeric ID. I've update my answer with what I believe is the best way to approach this now.

Comment: @philnash the quick start no longer has example of try/catch :( https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/csharp/rest/call-request

Comment: @BarryMSIH You're right, there is a section on handling errors here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/csharp-dotnet/usage-guide#handling-errors

Answer (score 5):

This is the example from the twilio dev site: https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/csharp-dotnet/usage-guide#handling-errors

```cs
    try
    {
        var message = MessageResource.Create(
            body: "This is the ship that made the Kessel Run in fourteen parsecs?",
            from: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("+15017122661"),
            to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("+15558675310")
        );

        Console.WriteLine(message.Sid);
    }
    catch (ApiException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        Console.WriteLine($"Twilio Error {e.Code} - {e.MoreInfo}");
    }
```